# Valgrind invalid size of read/write 1

Tags: valgrind

So Im writing a programe to combine 2 strings into 1, programe is working but I used valgrind and got many warnings, but i dont know whats wrong since im using ubuntu for few days and pretty much dont know valgrind yet.
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
char* fun (char* n1, char* n2);

int main(){

  char* string1 = "This home ";
  char* string2 = "is big";
  char* next;

  printf("Sklejony napis: %s\n", next=fun(string1, string2));
  free(next);
return 0;
}

char* fun (char* n1, char* n2)
{


  char* string3 = malloc(sizeof(char));



  int index_first = 0, index_second = 0;

  for(; n1[index_first] != '\0'; index_first++)
  {
    string3[index_first] = n1[index_first];

  }

  int index_third = index_first;

  for(; n2[index_second] != '\0'; index_second++)
  {

    string3[index_third] = n2[index_second];
    index_third++;

  }

  return string3;
}
```

And valgrind says this:

```
Invalid write of size 1
==2402==    at 0x400659: fun (plik.c:30)
==2402==    by 0x4005E0: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==  Address 0x5203041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==2402==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2402==    by 0x400627: fun (plik.c:22)
==2402==    by 0x4005E0: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==
==2402== Invalid write of size 1
==2402==    at 0x400698: fun (plik.c:39)
==2402==    by 0x4005E0: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==  Address 0x520304a is 9 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==2402==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2402==    by 0x400627: fun (plik.c:22)
==2402==    by 0x4005E0: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==
==2402== Invalid read of size 1
==2402==    at 0x4E88C80: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==2402==    by 0x4E8F848: printf (printf.c:33)
==2402==    by 0x4005FA: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==  Address 0x5203041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==2402==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2402==    by 0x400627: fun (plik.c:22)
==2402==    by 0x4005E0: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==
==2402== Invalid read of size 1
==2402==    at 0x4EB321D: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1301)
==2402==    by 0x4E884CA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==2402==    by 0x4E8F848: printf (printf.c:33)
==2402==    by 0x4005FA: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==  Address 0x520304f is 14 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==2402==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2402==    by 0x400627: fun (plik.c:22)
==2402==    by 0x4005E0: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==
==2402== Invalid read of size 1
==2402==    at 0x4EB3234: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1301)
==2402==    by 0x4E884CA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==2402==    by 0x4E8F848: printf (printf.c:33)
==2402==    by 0x4005FA: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==  Address 0x520304e is 13 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==2402==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2402==    by 0x400627: fun (plik.c:22)
==2402==    by 0x4005E0: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==
==2402== Invalid read of size 1
==2402==    at 0x4C35030: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2402==    by 0x4EB3171: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1319)
==2402==    by 0x4E884CA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==2402==    by 0x4E8F848: printf (printf.c:33)
==2402==    by 0x4005FA: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==  Address 0x520304f is 14 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==2402==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2402==    by 0x400627: fun (plik.c:22)
==2402==    by 0x4005E0: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==
==2402== Invalid read of size 1
==2402==    at 0x4C35040: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2402==    by 0x4EB3171: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1319)
==2402==    by 0x4E884CA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==2402==    by 0x4E8F848: printf (printf.c:33)
==2402==    by 0x4005FA: main (plik.c:13)
==2402==  Address 0x520304d is 12 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==2402==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2402==    by 0x400627: fun (plik.c:22)
==2402==    by 0x4005E0: main (plik.c:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to malloc that much space that contains both strings when you want to concatenate them or use string library where is function concat.

```
///you dont need to specify sizeof because of char is 1 byte information
string3 = malloc (strlen (n1) + strlen (n2) + 1);

/* the code is working there*/
for(; n2[index_second] != '\0'; index_second++)
{
 string3[index_third] = n2[index_second];
 index_third++;
}

///there you have to add \0 terminator at end of 
///function because of loop it is going only to \0
string3[index_third]='\0';
```

Comment: thanks, but my task was to concatenate them without any known fuction, i have to make my own :)

Comment: i edited the version before you only add null terminator at end and extend the size of string if you are not able to use string library please check strlen(length of string) its very simple to implement your own strlen function which you can use

Comment: Actually I can use strlen but as you said its easy to make so not big deal, but now I checked this code on windows compiler and there is no error but programe stopped working after running

Comment: my code is working so i dont know where is failure maybe you dont have included libraries ....

Comment: I do have these  <stdio.h><string.h><stdlib.h> ; sometimes it works but another time it doesnt. anyway i used valgrind again and these warnings from 1st post are still there

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* fun (char* n1, char* n2);

int main(){

  char* string1 = "This home ";
  char* string2 = "is big";
  char* next;

  printf("Sklejony napis: %s\n", next=fun(string1, string2));
  free(next);
return 0;
}

char* fun (char* n1, char* n2)
{


  char* string3;
  string3 = malloc(sizeof(strlen(n1) + strlen(n2) + 1 ));




  int index_first = 0, index_second = 0;

  for(; n1[index_first] != '\0'; index_first++)
  {
    string3[index_first] = n1[index_first];

  }

  int index_third = index_first;

  for(; n2[index_second] != '\0'; index_second++)
  {

    string3[index_third] = n2[index_second];
    index_third++;

  }

  string3[index_third]='\0';
  return string3;
}
```